# Python eval() in Lua

Tags: python, lua, eval, lua-table

I have the following Lua code:

```
ow = { {move, 4, 5, Down}, { }, ...}

...

if ow[n][1] == "move" then
    joypad.set({ ow[n][4] = true })
```

This code returns an error. I want to have it work as if I typed:

```
joypad.set({ Down = true })
```

In python I would handle this situation like:

```
eval('joypad.set({ {0} = true })'.format(ow[n][4]))
```

Is there a similar or different way I can do this in Lua?

Comment: I'm not sure you should have been handling it like that in Python...

Comment: Your Python code is invalid, that `eval()` will fail (as Python won't be able to execute Lua). You should not be using `eval()` in any case, I'm sure there are far better ways to handle that in Python.

Comment: I assume that by `{move, 4, 5, Down}` you mean `{"move", 4, 5, "Down"}`. You may want to edit your question to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write it thus:

```
joypad.set({ [ow[n][4]] = true })
```

Note the brackets around "`ow[n][4]`".

...and you may omit the parentheses:

```
joypad.set{ [ow[n][4]] = true }
```

The rule is this: if a table key isn't a lexical identifier or string, you need to put it inside brackets.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your other question, yes Lua does have something like `eval` -- it's called `loadstring`:

```
local setjoy = ("joypad.set { %s = true }"):format(ow[n][4])
loadstring(setjoy)()
```

But as Niccolo's answer has shown, there's a much more straightforward approach for what you're after.